# Starting with $13^{2013}$ can we get $2013^{13}$ by the following process.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is the problem that I found in a question paper. The problem is:

**A positive integer is written on the board. We repeatedly erase its unit digit and add 4 times that digit to what remains. Starting with the number $13^{2013}$ can we ever end up at $2013^{13}$.**

I really don't know how to solve these kind of problems.

Firstly I thought that I should start by finding the last digit of $13^{2013}$ but this method is not ideal for such kind of problems.

What should be my approach to solve these kind of problems.

Please help me in learning a new thing in mathematics.

Comment: Usually with such problems the answer should be "no, it is impossible". And the way to prove this, is to find something that is invariant through the process. Here, try to prove that the remainder when you divide by 3 is invariant.

Comment: Mathematically, one iteration is $f(x)=\lfloor\frac{x}{10}\rfloor+40(\frac{x}{10}-\lfloor\frac{x}{10}\rfloor)=    \frac{x}{10}-39\lfloor\frac{x}{10}\rfloor$

Comment: @AvZ A much more natural definition of the function is described below as $P(n) = P(10a+b) = a+4b$ where $n=10a+b$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ and $0\leq b\leq 9$.  If you wish to define it with floor functions, you have made an error as your number might not even be an integer.  $f(x) = \lfloor \frac{x}{10}\rfloor + 4(x - 10\cdot \lfloor \frac{x}{10}\rfloor) = 4x - 39\lfloor \frac{x}{10}\rfloor$.  You forgot to distribute $40$ onto $\frac{x}{10}$.

Comment: I can't leave a single comment without a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To simplify notation, for $n=10a+b$ with $a\in\mathbb{N}$ and $b\in\{0,1,2,\dots,9\}$ define $P(n)=P(10a+b) = a+4b$.  That is to say, $P(n)$ is precisely the function you describe of deleting the final digit and adding 4 times the deleted digit to the rest of the number.

Note that $13|n \Leftrightarrow 13|P(n) \Leftrightarrow 13|P^k(n)$  (try to prove this if you haven't seen it before)

Since we start with $13^{2013}$, clearly $13|13^{2013}$ so by applying $P$ multiple times we ask if we can ever get to $2013^{13}$

Notice however that $13\nmid 2013^{13}$ since $13$ is prime and $13\nmid 2013$ (by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic and since the prime decomposition of $2013$ is $3\cdot 11\cdot 61$)

It follows then that there does not exist a $k$ such that $P^k(13^{2013})=2013^{13}$ since the L.H.S. is a multiple of $13$ while the R.H.S. is not.

Comment: $13\mid n \Leftrightarrow 13\mid 10a+b \Leftrightarrow b\equiv -10a\pmod{13} \Leftrightarrow b\equiv 3a\pmod{13} \Leftrightarrow 4b\equiv 12a\equiv -a\pmod{13} \Leftrightarrow 13\mid a+4b$

Answer (score 4):

The other option -

Note that $3 \mid 2013$, and $3 \nmid 13^k$

$10a+b = 9a +(a+b) \equiv (a+b) \bmod 3 \\
a+4b = (a+b)+3b \equiv (a+b) \bmod 3 \\
\therefore 10a+b \equiv a+4b \bmod 3$

The digit-erasure process transforms $10a+b$ into $a+4b$ and preserves the  $\pmod 3$ congruence class

Since $2013^{13}$ and $13^{2013}$ are in different congruence classes $\pmod 3$, the erasure process cannot transform one into the other.

Comment: I particularly like this solution since divisibility tests for 2,3,5,9 is usually considered common knowledge.  My solution relied on divisibility by 13, which although hinted at in the problem statement, is much less common to know.  If anyone is curious, http://www.savory.de/maths1.htm contains tests for divisibility by all primes below 50 and hints at the general procedure for arbitrary prime above that.

Comment: @JMoravitz I wonder if the question setter was intending the mod 3 or the mod 13 solution? or maybe - as it worked out - both?